# Code for quicks sort with insertion sort not working

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, optimization

So i attempted to use insertion sort with quick sort to try to speed it up, but it isn't working for a reason i can't figure out. The sort operated correctly before i added the insertion sort part.

```
void QuickSort(int data[], int p, int r)
  {
   if (p < r)
   {
       if (r - p < 10)
       {
           InsertionSort(data, p, r);
           return;
       }
       int pivotIndex = Partition(data, p, r);
       QuickSort(data, p, pivotIndex - 1);
       QuickSort(data, pivotIndex + 1, r);
   }

}
void InsertionSort(int data[], int p,int r)
{
   int i, j, temp;
   for (i = p; i<(r-p)+1; i++)
   {
      temp = data[i];
      for (j = i - 1; j >= 0 && data[j]>temp; j--)
                data[j + 1] = data[j];
      data[j + 1] = temp;
   }
}
```

Full Source code here:-https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9856210

Comment: If you're looking for speed, `std::sort` is the way here.

Comment: Oh i do realize that std::sort is way way faster than anything i could write, i am just doing this for the sake of the learning experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm wondering why you need to do

```
i < (r-p) + 1
```

I have my suspicious on that part.

```
void InsertionSort(int data[], int p,int r)
{
   int i, j, temp;
   for (i = p; i <= r; i++)
   {
      temp = data[i];
      for (j = i - 1; j >= 0 && data[j]>temp; j--)
         data[j + 1] = data[j];
      data[j + 1] = temp;
   }
}
```

Comment: That would definitely ruin the sort, it is important to note that both of these work correctly on their own, so i guess my mistake is in integrating them but i have no idea what could be wrong.

Comment: May I have the input sample and the desired output?

Comment: @user2968505 I just editted my answer. Could you check it with your compiler?

Comment: Oh i screwed up badly there, your fix work thank you very much.